# Issues with pointer within array of structs

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, struct, embedded

This is a C issue I'm putting on a microcontroller.

I have a struct that contains values for my hardware instance 'Node', each value relates to a 'register'.

A 'register' is a struct that contains details on read/write privileges. status flags... etc and a pointer to a the related value within the Node struct.

I have an array of these registers. See code below:

```
typedef struct
{
    uint8_t         Address;
    uint32_t        *Value; 
    typebool        ReadOnly;
    uint8_t         Type;
    typebool        QueryRequest; //Has host queried this register?
    typebool        UpdateOccured; //has a register been updated?
} typeRegister;

struct typeNode
{
    uint32_t    FlagSetter;
    uint32_t    FlagClearer;
    uint32_t    Flags;
    uint32_t    Colour;
    uint32_t    HeldFor;
    uint32_t    Team;
    uint32_t    UpdateOccured; //has a register been updated?
} Node;


typeRegister Registers[6] = 
{
    {0,&Node.FlagSetter,False,type_int32,False,False},
    {1,&Node.FlagClearer,False,type_int32,False,False},
    {2,&Node.Flags,False,type_int32,False,False},
    {3,&Node.Colour,False,type_int32,False,False},
    {4,&Node.HeldFor,False,type_int32,False,False},
    {5,&Node.Team,False,type_int32,False,False}
};
```

With my understanding of pointers, this should allow access to a register value by using the syntax `uint32_t Value3 = *Registers[3].Value` or `*Registers[3].Value = 100`.

However, when I try and do this, Value is never correctly assigned or read.

If, however, I assign the pointer at run time (i.e. `Registers[3].Value = &Node.Colour;`) it DOES work.

Is there a limitation to being able to declare pointers within structs outside of run time?

---

I have done a bunch of value and pointer setting, getting and assigning, and it seems that if I assign Registers[n].Value = &Node.Colour at runtime, it works, but not if it's assigned at compile time:

```
                    uint32_t Value = 0;
                    Value = Node.Colour; // Value == 0xAB || &Node.Colour == 0x0047
                    
                    uint32_t *ValuePtr;
                    ValuePtr = &Node.Colour; // ValuePtr == 0x0047  |  *ValuePtr == 0xAB
                    
                    uint32_t Value2 = *ValuePtr; // Value2 == 0xAB
                    
                    uint32_t Value3 = *Registers[3].Value; // Value3 == 0xFE04FE00
                    
                    uint32_t *ValuePtr2; 
                    ValuePtr2 = Registers[3].Value; // ValuePtr2 == 0x0000  |  *ValuePtr2 = 0x00470000 <-- WRONG
                    
                    Registers[3].Value = &Node.Colour; // Assign pointer at run time
                    
                    uint32_t *ValuePtr3; 
                    ValuePtr3 = Registers[3].Value; // ValuePtr3 == 0x0047 |  *ValuePtr3 == 0xAB <-- RIGHT
```

Cheers for any help.

Comment: OT: What's the sense of `Address` being a duplication of the index?

Comment: I was able to compile your code with a few typedefs to fill in the gaps, and it works exactly as expected (cc --version = "Apple clang version 11.0.0"). So I don't think it's a C issue.

Comment: Code like this requires setting up the pointer values at link time, so there may be issues with your linker.  This should work (and works on "normal" setups like Linux), so it may be an issue with your microcontroller linker.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the microcontroller you use and its compiler, including version. Extend your code snippets to a [mre], show the commands to compile and link, with maximum warning level, and any output thereof.

Comment: @thebusybee More likely, this is just related to the project settings and CRT so what's most relevant is to know the IDE and how the project was created. I posted a generic answer covering most microcontroller systems.

Answer (score 1):

It is very common that MCU projects, no matter tool chain, have two mutually exclusive alternatives upon creation:

- One option named "fast/minimal start-up". This creates faster start from power-up, but deviates from standard C.
- One option named "standard C/ANSI C/strict" etc. This creates conforming C language behavior.

What this means is that the C standard requires that all variables with *static storage duration* - those declared outside a function at file scope or as `static` - shall be initialized at a point before main() is called.

For microcontrollers that means that these variables need to have their values copied down from flash to RAM by the CRT start-up code that runs before main() starts. This takes a bit of time to do, depending on how many variables there are. (And in case of C++, default constructors will get executed too, adding even more overhead.) Some particularly bad CRT does this initialization first, while running on some slow internal RC system clock, then only switches over to the fast oscillator setting when you explicitly tell it to do that in main().

To avoid issues caused by slow start-up, the "fast/minimal" option is there. If enabled in your case, it means that code initializaing static storage duration variables ***will be ignored***. Such as this:

```c
typeRegister Registers[6] = 
{
    {0,&Node.FlagSetter,False,type_int32,False,False},
    ...
```

You won't get any compiler warnings about this, the compiler will silently get ignore the initializer list. Instead you'll have to assign it in run-time:

```c
Registers[0] = (Registers){0,&Node.FlagSetter,False,type_int32,False,False};
...
```

So if using a minimal, non-standard setup, you will have to adapt the way you write code accordingly. For example by placing the above run-time initialization in some init() function for the applicable driver.

Or if you *don't* want this behavior, pick the standard C mode when creating the project.

---

Unrelated to your question, the struct members are poorly organized in terms of alignment. It doesn't matter if you use a 8/16 bitter without alignment, but it does matter if you use a MCU with alignment such as Cortex M. In that case, the struct members should get properly organized to not cause bloat padding needlessly:

```c
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t        *Value; 
    uint8_t         Address;
    typebool        ReadOnly;
    uint8_t         Type;
    typebool        QueryRequest; //Has host queried this register?
    typebool        UpdateOccured; //has a register been updated?
} typeRegister;
```

This is 100% equivalent in terms of functionality but doesn't allocate 3 waste-of-space bytes per struct object on a 32 bitter/32 bit address bus.

Comment: Should have clarified, it's an 8 bit processor. So (if I believe correctly) a char / uint8_t type takes up 1 byte, and larger values multiples there of.

Comment: This answer, I think, hits the root of my issue. I fugured it would be something along these lines. I don't like the addition of an init function. But if needs must, then so be it. Cheers.

Comment: @Pyro "a char / uint8_t type takes up 1 byte, and larger values multiples there of" That's true for every mainstream computer of any kind. But 8-bitters usually don't have alignment so you can arrange the struct any way you want, given that there's no requirement that a 16 bit pointer must be read at an even address.

Comment: @Pyro Regarding the actual issue, just create a new project in your IDE (which one is it?) then pay attention to whatever options the IDE presents in some "wizard" upon project creation. Then you will know if this is the cause of the problem or not.